# API and basic application in the same Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, design-patterns

I have a question while building application and stack with some ideas.

My ***controllers*** directory looks like this now:

- -rw-r--r--@  1 sesharim  staff   779B Sep 24 22:01 application_controller.rb
- -rw-r--r--@  1 sesharim  staff    66B Sep 28 15:21 events_controller.rb
- -rw-r--r--   1 sesharim  staff    51B Sep 24 22:10 places_controller.rb
- drwxr-xr-x   4 sesharim  staff   136B Sep 28 14:52 v1

and almost the same for ***v1*** directory:

- -rw-r--r--   1 sesharim  staff    73B Sep 28 14:52 events_controller.rb
- -rw-r--r--   1 sesharim  staff    55B Sep 28 14:52 places_controller.rb

As you can see, i have duplicates, which will have the same functionality, but controllers that in ***controllers*** will be for users, and controllers that in ***v1***, will be for API requests.

By trying to keep best practices while developing API, and keep general application in one place i got a problem, how to organize in in correct way. Just don't want to keep duplicates, and keep it DRY as possible. How to be with routes? Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has a great [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) on this topic where he also explains why it is not a violation of DRY. Your API controllers are responsible for different views, so although they might look similar and are named the same way, these controllers serve a different purpose than your html controllers.